# Simple function asking for positive integer and verifying input

Tags: python, function, input, integer

I'm simply trying to create a function asking for a positive integer and then verifying that the input is indeed a positive integer:

```
def int_input(x):
    x = input('Please enter a positive integer:')
    if x != type(int()) and x < 1:
        print("This is not a positive integer, try again:")
    else:
        print(x)

int_input(x)
```

It's giving me "NameError: name 'x' is not defined".

It's so ridiculously simple I feel like I should have found lots of posts on this so maybe I'm blind...

Thanks!

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: It is unclear why your function takes `x` as an argument in the first place, but your last line definitely passes an undefined `x` variable.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri 3.5

Comment: `x != type(int())` is discouraged. Try using `isinstance` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
def int_input():
    x = input('Please enter a positive integer:')
    if x != type(int()) and x < 1:
        print("This is not a positive integer, try again:")
    else:
        print(x)

int_input()
```

It should be like this, you cannt call a function `int_input()` without declaring `x`

Answer (score 0):

You defined the function, and then call it passing `x` as parameter, but `x` is indeed not defined in `int_input(x)`'s scope (global in this case).

Some more correct version of your code would be:

```
def int_input(x):
    if x != type(int()) and x < 1:
        print("This is not a positive integer, try again:")
    else:
        print(x)

x = input('Please enter a positive integer:')
int_input(x)
```

Besides, this comparison:

```
x != type(int())
```

will always be `False` since `type(int())` will always be `int` (a type) while `x` is a value. Oh and you should pass a value to `int()` too, otherwise it always returns `0`.

Comment: I just don't understand why I wouldn't be able to include the x = input(...) part into the function so that I just have to call the function to ask the user for an input?As for the second part, I did have a feeling it would give me issues

Comment: You can, but in this case you wouldn't need to pass any parameters to your function. So you'd change its definition to `def int_input():` and invoke it by doing `int_input()` instead of `int_input(x)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean to have the code reject float values as well as negative values? In this case you need to say `or` rather than `and` in your if statement.

```
def int_input(x):
    if x != type(int()) or x < 1:
        print("This is not a positive integer, try again:")
    else:
        print(x)

x = input('Please enter a positive integer:')
int_input(x)
```

Additionally, I'm not sure which version of python you are using. 3.x should work fine but if you are using 2.x you will get a fault if the user enters a string. To protect against this you can add an except like this:

```
def int_input(x):
    if x != type(int()) or x < 1:
        print("This is not a positive integer, try again:")
    else:
        print(x)

try:
    x = input('Please enter a positive integer:')
    int_input(x)
except:
    print("This is not a positive integer, try again:")
```